# error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'using'

Tags: c++, static

this is my header:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

class Math
{
    private:
        static enum names {amin = 27 , ali = 46};

    public:
        static void displayMessage();

}


#endif // HEADER_H
```

and this is the header definition:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;

void Math::displayMessage()
{
    cout<<amin<<setw(5)<<ali<<endl;
}
```

and this is the main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;

enum Math::names;

int main()
{
    Math::displayMessage();
}
```

i got these errors:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'using'  
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'using'
```

one of them is for main and the other is for header definition,
i have encountered several time in my programming,
could explain that for me in this situation,

please help me

best regards

Amin khormaei

Comment: On a side note, [`using namespace std;` is evil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/).

Comment: The answer to this question helped me to find a similar but not identical error in a large C++ solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After preprocessing, your source code<sup>[1]</sup> for your "header definition" becomes like

```
// iostream contents

// iomanip contents


class Math
{
    private:
        static enum names {amin = 27 , ali = 46};

    public:
        static void displayMessage();

}

using namespace std;

void Math::displayMessage()
{
    cout<<amin<<setw(5)<<ali<<endl;
}
```

Let's now see `error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'using'`. Where is `using` in the above code? **What is it before `using`?**

```
}
^ This    

using namespace std;
```

Because of the part of the error that says `missing ';'`, we must add that missing `;`.

```
};
 ^
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> <sub>More precisely called a "translation unit".</sub>

Answer (score 7):

You're missing a `;` after the definition of `class Math`.

Answer (score 0):

> missing ';' before 'using'

Just read what it tells you. There is a missing ; before `using`. Then look at your code, where did you use `using`? (the compiler likely told you the line)

```
#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;
```

What's before `using`? The header include.

The compiler most likely goes through your code in a linear manner, so what it did when it saw `#include "Header.h"` was to go through that file. Meaning that the error will be the very end of "Header.h". And indeed, there is a missing ; at the end of the class declaration, just like the compiler told you.